# How does a covergroup handle with an event handle sampling when enabling strobe?

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, verification

I am curious as to how the sampling happens in a SystemVerilog `covergroup` when we have an event specified and we also use `type_option.strobe = 1` for said `covergroup`.  For example:

```
covergroup c @(posedge clk)
 type_option.strobe=1;
```

`strobe` implies sampling happens in the Postponed region, however the `@(posedge clk)` as an event is evaluated at the Active region. How does the sampling function resolve this?

I tried reading the LRM, but it wasn't very cohesive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `type_option.strobe = 0`, the default, sampling occurs immediately in whatever region the sampling event gets triggered. In some odd cases, that could mean sampling multiple times within the same time slot.

When `type_option.strobe = 1`, the sampling event just schedules the actual covergroup sampling to occur *once* in the postponed region.

Answer (score 0):

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, Table 19-3—*Coverage group type (static) options*:

> **strobe**=*boolean*
>
> When true, all samples happen at the end of the time
> slot, like the `$strobe` system task.

Also, section 4.4.2.9 *Postponed events region*:

> `$monitor`, `$strobe`, and other similar events are scheduled in the
> Postponed region.

Therefore, setting `strobe=1` forces the sampling to occur in the Postponed region.  If `strobe=0`, sampling is not forced into the Postponed region.